# How do you use std::system_error with GetLastError?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11

If I call a Win32 function that reports errors via GetLastError, for example [RegisterClassEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), how do I throw a std::system_error for that error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check on the value of `GetLastError()` like

```
DWORD dwErrVal = GetLastError();
std::error_code ec (dwErrVal, std::system_category());
throw std::system_error(ec, "Exception occurred");
```

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/system_error/error_code/error_code/) for `error_code` and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/system_error/system_error/system_error/) for `std::system_error`.

Comment: Is it generic_category? Looking at the vc11 implementation it looks like maybe it should be system_category.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know it existed!

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be working for me.  GetLastError() is returning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, but the system_error::what simply says "unknown error"

Comment: system_error is for errno codes, not Win32 codes.  They're different. http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/d33ca604e6a55888937840570a5cd17d-76c1546f7ca7c2c00921bccdb34ec2d1

Comment: @MooingDuck I think msvc's system_category implementation *is* meant for codes returned by GetLastError() but it only returns a proper message for a small subset of all codes - at least for VS2013 - and ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER is not one of them. See _Winerror_map in syserror.cpp in the crt source code..

Comment: The whole `std::system_category()` thing in C++11 is a disaster when it comes to implementing on Win32 platform. Check **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746372/system-error-categories-and-standard-system-error-codes)** out. There is basically no provision in the standard for systems which have *both* `errno` *and* native error codes.

Comment: @stijn AFAIK, syserror.cpp only defines Windows to POSIX mapping, by design, what does not cover all Windows errors. However, other Windows codes are covered too. In VS2017, `std::error_code(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, std::system_category()).message();` gives "The parameter is incorrect." as expected.

Comment: @RustyX Not true. System error codes should be used with `system_category`, **and** it will be comparable to `std::errc` constants. If using Visual C++ 2015 or later (available when you commented), it is true that `std::error_code(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, std::system_category()) == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory` *and* `std::error_code(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND, std::system_category()) == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory`.

Comment: I can add to this, that `boost::system::error_code(::GetLastError(), boost::system::system_category())` works as expected on msvc2013; boost 1_59 at least

Answer (score 9):

Be aware that comparing a `std::error_code` in the category of `std::system_category()` doesn't generally work with the `std::errc` enumeration constants depending on your vendor. E.g.

`std::error_code(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, std::system_category()) != std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory)`

Certain vendors require using `std::generic_category()` for that to work.

In MinGW `std::error_code(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, std::system_category()).message()` won't give you the correct message.

For a truly portable and robust solution I would recommend subclassing both `std::system_error` and `std::system_category` to `windows_error` and `windows_category` and implement the correct functionality yourself. YMMV, VS2017 has been reported to work as one would expect.

Comment: Someone has got to have made this alreadyright?  But I can't find one :(

Comment: I am writing in 2017, so I am at a big advantage. This said, there are several problems with your answer.

The reason your first example failed was because your should have used `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. Secondly, even `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` will work under Visual C++ 2017 (but not 2013), as long as you use `system_category`. Yes, it only works correctly when one uses `system_category`, but not `generic_category`. Microsoft has made it work very well.