# How to throw an std::system_error exception from a FAILED(HRESULT)?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, com, throw

This is [how to throw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855015/6923555) ordinary Win32 errors correctly, automatically retrieving the error description, and it works marvellously well:

```
if (!SomeWinFunc()) {
  throw std::system_error(GetLastError(),
    std::system_category(),
    "SomeWinFunc crashed badly");
}
```

However, I'm uncertain on how to deal with COM errors, which are checked [idiomatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474(v=vs.85).aspx) like this:

```
HRESULT hr = comObj->SomeFunc();
if (FAILED(hr)) {
  throw std::system_error(hr, // <-- is it correct here?
    std::system_category(),
    "SomeFunc crashed right now");
}
```

Is it correct to pass an `HRESULT` to `system_error`, or there is another way to throw exceptions from a COM function?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @MichaelGunter, I still didn't implement a 100% correct solution (possibly starting with your code), but since my needs are simply dealing with system COM objects, the approach I wrote in the question just works, I ran several tests. I plan to go deeper on this as soon as I find time.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, I handle this using the Microsoft standard `_com_error` exception type, which can be easily raised by one of the following.

```
_com_util::CheckError(hr); // throws when FAILED(hr)
_com_issue_error(hr); // throws always
```

A Win32 error can be converted to an `HRESULT` like so:

```
hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
```

However, this means that you have to deal with a new exception type, which may be problematic. To do this the pure STL way, I think you need to derive a new `error_category` and use that instead of `system_category`. I would look at the `<system_error>` header and copy the implementation of `system_category`, updating as necessary for `HRESULT`s.

Ideally, the different [facility codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx) in the `HRESULT` would be served by different `error_category` implementations -- doing so would very effectively communicate the exception and its source. But that is tricky, and you can probably get away with a single `com_category` that deals with `HRESULT`s generically.

Comment: It's important to note, that you **must not** pass an `HRESULT` when using the `std::system_category` as the context. That category is meant for use with error codes returned by `GetLastError`. For example, if you pass the COM success code `S_FALSE`, it would get interpreted as `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`. Information on how to implement your custom `error_category` can be found at [System error support in C++0x - part 4](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-4.html).

Comment: @IInspectable `S_FALSE` is not a good example, because it is not an error code. So there is no reason to throw it. The *error* values which a `HRESULT` can represent do not overlap with the error codes returned by `GetLastError`, because `HRESULT` errors are always negative. So in my opinion a special category for `HRESULT` is not required aslong as you only throw values for which `FAILED(hr)==true`.

Comment: @zett42: That depends on your code logic. A successful COM call can yield a condition, from which you cannot recover, and need to throw. Even if that weren't the case, you still need a custom error category to produce error messages. While `FormatMessage` can be used with system-defined `HRESULT` values, things look different when you deal with customer-defined codes. You need additional information to turn those into error messages, namely the module handle. That needs to be encoded in the category, since you cannot pass additional information alongside the error code.

Comment: Found another reason to create a dedicated `error_category` for `HRESULT`: to be able to examine error codes in a generic way. E. g. the following doesn't work: `std::error_code e(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND), std::system_category()); if(e == std::errc::no_such_file_or_directory){/*do something*/}`. This could be solved by overriding `std::error_category::default_error_condition()` in a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

This article has a great walkthrough of how to define an `std::error_code` for COM API errors: https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121648-fitting-com-into-c-system-error-handling

The gist of it is to just use `_com_error` to get the message, and the rest is mostly `std` boilerplate for creating error_codes.